# override given variable in object | Javascript React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const [letters, setLetters] = useState({
    A: false,
    B: false,
    C: false
})

function handleClick(input){
    setLetters((prevLetters) => ({
        ...prevLetters,
        [input]: true
    }))
}

handleClick("A")
```

How do I manage that, depending on the input, the correct letter is set to true? So if the input is A, it should be set to true in the letters object.

Comment: I don't see problems with your code, can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) would be a good choice here.

```js
const [letters, setLetters] = useState(new Map());

function handleClick (input) {
    setLetters(letters.set(input, true));
}

handleClick("A");
```

If you wish that `input` MUST be A, B, or C, then you can use an if statement:

```js
const [letters, setLetters] = useState(new Map([
    ["A", false], // default values for map
    ["B", false],
    ["C", false],
]));

function handleClick (input) {
    if (!letters.has(input)) return; // if map doesnt have it, stop

    setLetters(letters.set(input, true));

    // can also use letters.set(input, false) to "turn it off"
}

handleClick("A");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override the existing properties on the `letters` object you can do something like this

```js
const lettersObject = {
  A: false,
  B: false,
  C: false,
};

const [letters, setLetters] = useState(lettersObject);

function handleClick(input) {
  setLetters({
    ...lettersObject,
    [input]: true,
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
  function handleClick(input) {
    setLetters((prevLetters) => ({
      letters: {
        ...prevLetters,
        input: true
      }
    }));
  }
```